# ( Ctrl + / ) Shortcut does not work properly in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows.

`ctrl` + `/` does not work after a while I started VSC, so I have to restart in every few minutes.

Sometimes, it suddenly works again even though I didn't restart it, so I have no idea why is this happening.

Just in case, I've checked my keyboard shortcuts,

but nothing other than the default one is bound on `Ctrl` + `/`.

My installed extensions on VSC are listed below.

- Beautify
- Dracula Official
- ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets
- HTML to JSX
- One Dark Pro
- open in browser

I haven't installed any other extensions in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Linux. Perhaps you have keybinding conflicts with the toggleExplaneMode function. This function allows you to deploy a more detailed description of tags or functions in the dialog box. I changed my keyboard shortcuts "ctrl + /" also attached to toggleExplaneMode and this problem did not appear anymore.

How to see keybinding conflicts - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings